# How do I check if a set is a vector space using axioms?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> A. Check that $\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix} \middle\vert\; x, y \in \Bbb R \right\} = \Bbb R^2$
>   (with the usual addition and scalar
>   multiplication) satisfies all of the parts in the definition of a vector
>   space.
>
> B. Check that the complex numbers $ \Bbb C =  \{ x + iy \mid i^2 = −1 \wedge x, y \in \Bbb R  \}$,
>   satisfy all of the parts in the definition of a vector space over  $\Bbb C $.
>   Make sure you state carefully what your rules for vector addition
>   and scalar multiplication are.
>
> C.  What would happen if you used $\Bbb R$ as the base field for part B (try comparing
>   to problem A).

Please note, I cannot assume any of the axioms, I don't know how to prove them given the criteria. Some direction/going over a few would be very helpful. Additionally explaining why it works would be beneficial. Furthermore, I cannot explain Part C even with an intuitive understanding that both parts are vector spaces.

Comment: You don't need to *assume* the axioms – you need to *prove* them! Just prove them one by one.

Comment: First thing **to do**: find out what *are* the parts of the definition of a vector space.  Can you list them?

Comment: @GrahamKemp The definition of a vector space is as follows:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector space is a set of entities closed under operations of *vector addition* and *scalar multiplication* $(+, \cdot)$.

That requires commutativity, associativity, identity, and inversion of vector addition, and associativity, and identity of scalar multiplication, as well as distribution of scalar sums, and of vector sums.

Adopting the convention of denoting vectors using uppercase letters, and scalars using lowercase letters, we have, for all vectors $X,Y,Z$ and scalars $r,s$:

$$\begin{array}{lll}
A1. & \text{Commutativity of vector addition }(+): & X+Y=Y+X  
\\ A2. & \text{Associativity of vector addition: } & (X+Y)+Z=X+(Y+Z)
\\ A3. & \text{Vector addition identity }({\bf 0}): & {\bf 0}+X = X+{\bf 0} = X
\\ A4. & \text{Existence of additive inverse for every vector: }&(\forall X)(\exists {-X})( X+(-X)={\bf 0})
\\ M5. & \text{Associativity of scalar multiplication }(\cdot): & r(s\cdot X)=(rs)\cdot X
\\ M6. & \text{Scalar multiplication identity }(1): & 1\cdot X=X 
\\ D7. & \text{Distributivity of scalar sums: } & (r+s)\cdot X=r\cdot X+s\cdot X 
\\ D8. & \text{Distributivity of vector sums: } & r\cdot(X+Y)=r\cdot X+r\cdot Y
\end{array}$$

So for each set identify the relevant "vector addition" and "scalar multiplication" operations and demonstrate, one by one, how each of these eight properties holds (or doesn't).